# How to set callback to execute after all the tinyMCE editors have been initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've loaded a tinyMCE editor using `wp_editor` function of Wordpress.

Now, I want to set value of that editor after it gets initialized. I tried to do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    tinymce.get(...).setContent(...);
});
```

But it throws an error saying `Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined` because the editor has not been initialized. To confirm it I console logged using `console.log( tinymce.editors.length )` statement and it prints `0` but later when I inspected the variable `tinymce.editors` using browser console after the loading was done, the editor was there and I could manipulate it.

So, my conclusion was to wait for all the tinyMCE editors to be initialized then run the above code to change the editor's value. Note that I need to set the value using JS, not from the backend (php).

EDIT: I'm loading the JS scripts using following statement:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
```

And inside the `enqueue_scripts` function:

```
wp_enqueue_script(..., ..., true);
```

Please tell me if there's a way to accomplish this. And ask me if you need more information or I'm unclear.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/367031/edit) to show us how you're loading the JavaScript? Specifically, are you using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to do so?

Comment: @PatJ yes i'm using the `wp_enqueue_script` function to load the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for the specific editor manager to get added and then bind the `init` event handler to set content of the editor like this:

```
tinymce.on( 'addeditor', e => {
    if ( e.editor.id === <your_editor_id> ) {
        e.editor.on( 'init', event => {
            event.target.setContent( <your_editor_content> );
        });
    }
}, true );
```